# Saving file locally from JavaScript in WebView

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, cocoa, webview

OK, here's the big picture:

- We have a native Cocoa/OSX app
- Inside this app there is a WebView
- Inside this WebView, there is a local web app, with its code residing in the app's bundle resources

Now, the thing is:

- Let's say I want to save a file FROM the web app (using JS), is that possible? And how?
- Do I sort of have to "forward" the contents back to Objective-C/Cocoa and have the "real" app do the saving?
- If the first point is possible (saving from JS), what about Sandboxing? How is that to be handled?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, my research hasn't brought up anything. The Webview (and its OSX-specific handling, in particular) doesn't seem to have much of a following. That's why I decided to see if anyone else has ever dealt with that same issue, here in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the file on the Cocoa side of things by intercepting a click on a link inside the `WebView` using a `WebPolicyDelegate`. I've accomplished this in a project using the following delegate method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender
        decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
        request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame
        decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
```

When it comes to sandboxing, it really depends what you are going to do with that file. 
If I'm not mistaken you can easily save files within the sandbox (e.g. `NSApplicationSupportDirectory`) and in case you're presenting a file dialog, the sandbox will be handled automatically.